# My LibGDX slider won't slide

Tags: java, libgdx, slider

As goes without saying, I'm a complete novice and I'm not too sure what to do.

When I run my application, the slider simply won't slide. I've looked everywhere, and the closest I got was thinking it may be something to do with a knob but I have no idea what specifically. It may be worth noting that I'm using the default LibGDX UI files.

```
 package com.angus;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class Audio extends ApplicationAdapter {
    Slider slider;
    Skin skin;
    Stage stage;



    @Override
    public void create () {

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        slider = new Slider(0.00f, 10.00f, 1.00f, false, skin);
        stage.addActor(slider);
        System.out.println(slider.getStyle());
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

This tells LibGDX to handle inputs from stage.

Answer (score 0):

Extending icarumbas' answer, at the beginning of the `render()` method, you need to clear the screen.

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(red, blue, green, alpha);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

`red`, `blue`, `green`, `alpha` are all floats of 0-1. If you wanted to make the background color white, you would use: `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);`

So render *clears the screen* then draws the slider.